# pool.demands for deployment jobs not working correctly in azure yaml pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-deployment, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-deployment

I have an azure pipeline yaml that my final goal is to manage and control the agent of the agent pool that launch each job of my pipeline. What I did is get and store in a variable de agent name that I want to use throw all my pipeline, and with the [pool.demands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/pool-demands?view=azure-pipelines&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops) property restrict the agent that can launch each job.

My specific case is that for jobs of type [job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) is working exactly how I want to, but not for [deployments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-jobs?view=azure-devops) job type. Here is a real example:

```
stages:
- stage:
  pool:
    name: "MyAgentPool"
  jobs:
    - job: GetCurrentAgentPool
      displayName: Save current agent pool
      steps:
        - checkout: none
        - task: PowerShell@2
          name: GetAgentNameJob
          displayName: Store current agent pool
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=AgentName;isoutput=true]$(Agent.Name)"
    
    - job:
      displayName: job type
      dependsOn:
        - GetCurrentAgentPool
      variables:
        AgentName: $[ dependencies.GetCurrentAgentPool.outputs['GetAgentNameJob.AgentName'] ]
      pool:
        name: "MyAgentPool"
        demands: Agent.Name -equals  $(AgentName)
      steps:
        - script: echo $(AgentName)

    - deployment:
      displayName: deployment type
      environment:  MyEnvironment
      dependsOn:
        - GetCurrentAgentPool
      variables:
        AgentName: $[ dependencies.GetCurrentAgentPool.outputs['GetAgentNameJob.AgentName'] ]
      pool:
        name: "MyAgentPool"
        demands: Agent.Name -equals  $(AgentName)
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:
              - script: echo $(AgentName)
```

If I execute this yaml, the result is that the 1º and 2º job is executed with no problem, but 3º one, the deployment job throws an error with no description. Here the result:

[image]

And if I drill down to see the error, as I said, there is nothing:

[image]

My first thought is that the variable "AgentName" is not storing correctly the value, but if I remove de pool.demand tag line then I can see that the value is correctly set with the print screen echo. Any Idea what is happening? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like a bug in how demand are resolved for deployment jobs. I hardcoded agent name in that condition and even that agent is available, the jobs is not picking it up showing me that `The agent request is not running because all potential agents are running other requests. Current position in queue: 1
No agents in pool DevLinux are currently able to service this request.` I would recommend you create a ticket on tech community https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-devops/bd-p/AzureDevOpsForum